# How can I use reference method in a UnaryOperator java 8

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface, unary-operator

Currently, I have a `UnaryOperator` like this

```
UnaryOperator<Object> defaultParser = obj -> obj;
```

I don't know if I can use a method reference in these kinds of operation. Example:

```
UnaryOperator<String> defaultParser = String::toString;
```

But with the generic way, not just `String`.

Comment: `Object::toString` then? Since `toString` is defined on object, that should be what you're looking for in "the generic way".

Comment: @SilvioMayolo but the Unary maybe receive an object, not just String, and I want that object back.

Comment: `String::toString` is not the same as `obj -> obj`, as the former will throw a `NullPointerException` for `null` input whereas the latter won’t. If that’s not a concern or even intended behavior, you can simply use `UnaryOperator<WhatEver> defaultParser = Objects::requireNonNull;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just  want to avoid the lambda expression, `UnaryOperator` has static [`identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html#identity--) method:

```
UnaryOperator<Object> defaultParser = UnaryOperator.identity();
```

If you specifically want a method reference (why??), you can define a method in your class

```
public static <T> T identity(T t) {
    return t;
}
```

Then you will be able to use it as a method reference:

```
UnaryOperator<Object> defaultParser = MyClass::identity;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can using the [`UnaryOperator.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html#identity()) as:

```
UnaryOperator<Object> defaultParser = UnaryOperator.identity();
```

which is defined with a lambda expression as

```
static <T> UnaryOperator<T> identity() {
    return t -> t;
}
```